# How to migrate postgresql database from 2.42 to 3.2.1

Tags: redmine

I am upgrading my server and migrating my redmine postgresql database. But the database format has changed between 2.4.2 and 3.2.1

How do I go about migrating the data?

Comment: Refer https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/5.8/html/installation_guide/sect-migrating_the_database . Hope it helps.

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade see step 4, the database update schema is done after upgrading the redmine installation.